# File System API to open folder in network drive

Tags: javascript, file-system-access-api

I want to be able to open a folder that is on a network drive from a website, ideally it would be the starting from this location when a users first opens the window.

Is it possible to have the shared network drive as the default location when it opens.

Comment: The browser's filesystem API doesn't let you specify the default location of the file dialog. The user will have to navigate to the network drive by hand.

Comment: @Barmar I thought that was the case but wanted to double check, it seems like a simple thing to achieve too.

Comment: It's prohibited for security reasons. You don't want a web site tricking the user into opening files from system folders.

Comment: Its actually from a Dynamics 365 site so it will not be public facing, it would be nice just to have the option (for internal user sites)

Comment: Browser security rules are designed for the general case. There's no way for the browser to know that this is a private site that should be given more permissions.